# Write C++ on Windows but use Linux System calls through a Linux emulator

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2010, cygwin

I would like to develop C++ on Windows because I prefer the Visual Studio IDE (eclipse on Linux isn't very nice). However, eventually I will migrate to Linux and some of the code I will be writing will use low-level OS system calls.

Is there any way I can install a Linux emulator (not sure what you call it) on Windows, write Linux system calls in Visual Studio 2012 and have these system calls target the emulator, rather than the Windows OS?

I have tagged VS2010 but I can use VS2012 also.

Windows OS is Win 7.

Comment: You might rather want to use portable libraries that abstract system calls away from you.

Comment: That seems like a pretty poor solution. You can write your code in Visual studio, and then compile on the command-line or via a custom build mode in VS [although don't ask me how to configure such a thing - it's been a long time [about 10 years] since I used Visual Studio, never mind for anything more sophisticated], using a secure shell (ssh) connection.

Comment: you know http://www.cygwin.com/ right? it provides a unix like environment within windows. but you would still have to compile applications within cygwin with something like g++. Maybe rather look around for a different IDE you can live with? Eclipse is by far not the only one out there

Answer (score 1):

You've already tagged your question with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). That seems like the best solution for what you want. Cygwin is basically a collection of programs which emulate a GNU/LInux environment through the use of a

> DLL (cygwin1.dll) which acts as a Linux API layer providing
>   substantial Linux API functionality.

Here's the link to the [documentation for its API](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/)

Edit: Most of the Cygwin source code that I've looked at is written in C++ and makes system calls using MS Windows API to do provide the *nix emulation. The source is well written and very readable (even to to a non-C++ programmer such as myself). I think using Cygwin would be a good transition from programming on Windows to a GNU/Linux environment.

Comment: So how would I "inform" Visual Studio this layer exists when compiling? I presume VS is going to throw compiler errors when encountering Linux system calls?

Comment: Sorry. I'm from a  *nix command-line background and don't have any experience with Visual Studio. There's some relevant info for a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926311/cygwin-in-visual-studio

The tutorials at http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/cygwin/ and http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/cygwin/import/ also look they might be useful.