# Error using library functions of cygwin compiled dll in visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cygwin

I am trying to call cygwin compiled dll in wisual studio environment.

If I compile dll which have function without any library (just return any number),
it works ok, but if I call for example stdio.h, and function with writing file, or just printf function, does not work ( in case of printf function has exited with code 1536).

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int myfunc() 
{
  char* strtxt = "test";
  FILE *hF = fopen( "Newlogtst.txt", "w" );   
  if(hF == 0)
  {
    return 5;
  }    
  fputs( (const char*)strtxt, hF );
  fclose(hF);
  return 1;
}

int tst()
{
     return 25;
}
```

function tst works ok, function myfunc make empty file `Newlogtst.txt` and shows exception .
`

> Exception thrown at 0x6113333A (cygwin1.dll) in CygwinDlltest.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004E0059.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

`
in visual studio I am using this code

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*PFN_HELLO)();
typedef void (*PFN_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT)();

int main()
{
    PFN_HELLO func;
    HMODULE hLib, h = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\cygwin1.dll")); 
    PFN_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT init = (PFN_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT) GetProcAddress(h,"cygwin_dll_init");
    init(); 

    hLib = LoadLibrary (TEXT("C:\\Cygwin\\home\\azatyan\\TestDynamicLink\\mydll.dll"));
    func = (PFN_HELLO) GetProcAddress (hLib, "myfunc");
    return func();      
}
```

please help what should I do to use library functions.

Comment: _function `myfunc` no_...._ could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926311/cygwin-in-visual-studio before you continue

Comment: LPs: actually it does make `Newlogtst.txt` file but empty, and exits with this exception - " Exception thrown at 0x6113333A (cygwin1.dll) in CygwinDlltest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004E0059.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. "

Comment: cup: Thanks, for link but I think it will not help, I do not want to change include header paths in visual studio, what I want is just load dll, call functions..

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't check the returncode of `GetProcAddress()`.
2. If you compile it in C++, the names are mangled differently, (which is why `GetprocAddress()` will return NULL btw.) because they are different compilers.

If you are just using basic functions like in your example, you should declare them as `extern "C"` so that they wont get mangled. Also make sure that the `__declspec export` statement are used correctly when compiling the DLL.

Comment: No function names are not mangled, I am debugging GetprocAddress is not NULL. it even makes ' Newlogtst.txt ' empty file...

Comment: Did you read this? https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.msvcrt-and-cygwin Looks like you didn't really initialize the cygwin CRT properly. Apparently cygwin_dll_init is not enough.

Comment: Thanks , I think , I should read how to initialize cygwin CRT properly. But still I do not now how can I call second function without any exception ?

Comment: From what I found via google, it's probably not possible or very hard as to not worth the bother. If the CRT is properly initialized, I would expect that `myfunc` will not crash anymore.